# Why does $H_2$ form on such a long time scale?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, astrophysics, universe

If we were trying to figure out the time scale for a gas-phase reaction between two hydrogen atoms in a molecular cloud (which has density $~10^4/$cm$^3$), apparently the reaction would happen on a time scale proportional to the inverse of the density multiplied by $10^{15}$ years. Aside from the cloud not being dense and the probability that a collision will surpass the activation energy is small, is the time elongated because you need to induce a dipole moment between two hydrogen atoms to actually bind them together?

Answer (score 2):

The rate of formation is much higher in the presence of dust.  There needs to be a mechanism for the energy of formation of the hydrogen molecule to be dissipated. Dissipating energy via a photon involves a forbidden transition.  Instead, the energy can be transferred to the vibrational lattice of a dust particle.

See [The Interstellar Abundance of the Hydrogen Molecule. I. Basic Processes](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1963ApJ...138..393G) for a detailed explanation.